How to disable prompt to enable Ubuntu pro
Here is the deal, this window is constantly popping out, ordering me to enable some "Ubuntu Pro". However this is a bug, because in reality we do not need to exable any ubuntu pro or install these updates - things are work well even without it, but constant popping out sabotages calm work.
Question is - how to disable this integrated annoying "ad" popup? 

Did you notice what the system is actually telling you? You are using lots of Universe packages that have known vulnerabilities, security updates available from upstream, and the Ubuntu community is not patching and uploading them. It's not an "ad," it's important information. You have decisions to make.

@user535733 reading "you need to do X" is different from "if you want to install - PLEASE enable ubuntu pro". I dont need to install ubuntu pro, so first claim is invalid in its very nature. And moreover its harsh naming - its abusing and annoying! If something is good and everyone really demands it - you dont need to advertise it in such abusive way!

Please keep in mind that "we" are not Canonical employees. We are your peer users who volunteer to help our fellows with questions. If you wish to complain, then please do so to Canonical Ltd.
